# XML - XSL Group by

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an XML like that :

```
 <produits>
  <produit>
    <CAT>GENCABI</CAT>
    <ITEMCODE>100-0190</ITEMCODE>
    <DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</DESCR>
    <EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</EXTDESC>
    <ITEMSET>100-9231</ITEMSET>
    <MANUF>1</MANUF>
    <IMAGE>100-0190</IMAGE>
    <TOC>8</TOC>
    <SUBTOC>3</SUBTOC>
  </produit>
  <produit>
    <CAT>GENCABI</CAT>
    <ITEMCODE>100-0240</ITEMCODE>
    <DESCR>Racleurs 25Mm No40 (6)                      Schein</DESCR>
    <EXTDESC>Racleurs 25Mm No40 (6) Schein</EXTDESC>
    <ITEMSET>100-9231</ITEMSET>
    <MANUF>1</MANUF>
    <IMAGE>100-0240</IMAGE>
    <TOC>8</TOC>
    <SUBTOC>3</SUBTOC>
  </produit>
  <produit>
    <CAT>GENCABI</CAT>
    <ITEMCODE>100-0379</ITEMCODE>
    <DESCR>Finger Plugger Henry Schein 25Mm B</DESCR>
    <EXTDESC>Pour condensation laterale de la gutta manche plastique. Rouge</EXTDESC>
    <ITEMSET>100-8766</ITEMSET>
    <MANUF>1</MANUF>
    <IMAGE>100-8766</IMAGE>
    <TOC>8</TOC>
    <SUBTOC>9</SUBTOC>
  </produit>
</produits>
```

I try to group Item by "Itemset".
I do it with a xsl like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="produit-by-ITEMSET" match="produit" use="ITEMSET" />
  <xsl:template match="/produits">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="produit">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)[1])">
    <produit>
        <xsl:attribute name="ParentItem">
          <xsl:value-of select="ITEMSET"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="../produit[ITEMSET=current()/ITEMSET]">
            <child>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ITEMCODE" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="DESCR" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="EXTDESC" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="MANUF" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="IMAGE" />
            </child>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </produit>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got What I whant for Item with multiples "Child" but I want to get rid of "Child" tag if there is only one child.

In my mind I've got something like "if count(select childs) > 1 display child tag, else didn't put child tag". But i'm pretty new with xsl / xml and a lillte bit lost...
If anyone have a tips...

Edit : Add xml output I have & I want

Output I have :

```
<produits>
<produit ParentItem="100-9231">
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0190</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0190</IMAGE>
</child>
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0583</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 30</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 30</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0583</IMAGE>
</child>
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0720</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21 Mm Taille 15</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21 Mm Taille 15</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0720</IMAGE>
</child>
</produit>
<produit ParentItem="968-2000">
<child>
<ITEMCODE>968-2000</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Aiguilles Medicales Terumo</DESCR>
<EXTDESC></EXTDESC>
<MANUF>5048</MANUF>
<IMAGE>968-2000</IMAGE>
</child>
</produit>
</produits>
```

Output I want :

```
<produits>
<produit ParentItem="100-9231">
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0190</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0190</IMAGE>
</child>
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0583</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 30</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 30</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0583</IMAGE>
</child>
<child>
<ITEMCODE>100-0720</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21 Mm Taille 15</DESCR>
<EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21 Mm Taille 15</EXTDESC>
<MANUF>1</MANUF>
<IMAGE>100-0720</IMAGE>
</child>
</produit>
<produit ParentItem="968-2000">
<ITEMCODE>968-2000</ITEMCODE>
<DESCR>Aiguilles Medicales Terumo</DESCR>
<EXTDESC></EXTDESC>
<MANUF>5048</MANUF>
<IMAGE>968-2000</IMAGE>
</produit>
</produits>
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you mean by something having "multiple children". _What_ has more than one child and what is the _child_? Also, make sure that your sample XML input contains a case where this condition is met.

Comment: I edit my xml cause I cut too much..
In my example If i apply xslt I got something like
[code]
<produit ParentItem=""><child>...</child><child>...</child></produit><produit ParentItem=""><child>...</child></produit>
[/code]
the second "produit" got only one child and the first one have multiple children.

i hope it's more understandable...
Thanks

Comment: This does not make it any clearer I'm afraid. Post the XML output you actually get _and_ the XML output you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I just add output I have and output I want.
I hope like that it's more clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you that you want your output to look like this....

```
<produits>
  <produit ParentItem="100-9231">
    <child>
      <ITEMCODE>100-0190</ITEMCODE>
      <DESCR>Broches Henry  Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</DESCR>
      <EXTDESC>Broches Henry Schein Longueur 21Mm Taille 40</EXTDESC>
      <MANUF>1</MANUF>
      <IMAGE>100-0190</IMAGE>
    </child>
    <child>
      <ITEMCODE>100-0240</ITEMCODE>
      <DESCR>Racleurs 25Mm No40 (6)                      Schein</DESCR>
      <EXTDESC>Racleurs 25Mm No40 (6) Schein</EXTDESC>
      <MANUF>1</MANUF>
      <IMAGE>100-0240</IMAGE>
    </child>
  </produit>
  <produit ParentItem="100-8766">
    <ITEMCODE>100-0379</ITEMCODE>
    <DESCR>Finger Plugger Henry Schein 25Mm B</DESCR>
    <EXTDESC>Pour condensation laterale de la gutta manche plastique. Rouge</EXTDESC>
    <MANUF>1</MANUF>
    <IMAGE>100-8766</IMAGE>
  </produit>
</produits>
```

First thing to mention is that your **xsl:for-each** can actually use the key to get the 'child' items in the 'group'

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)">
```

To avoid duplication of code, I would create a template to output the child items (without the **child** element though)

```
<xsl:template match="produit" mode="child">
   <xsl:copy-of select="ITEMCODE" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="DESCR" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="EXTDESC" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="MANUF" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="IMAGE" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you can test how many **child** items there are by counting the key

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)) > 1">
           <!-- Multiple children -->
       </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
           <-- One child -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

For multiple children, use the current for-each loop, but call the template

```
       <xsl:for-each select="key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)">
            <child>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="child" />
            </child>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

For single children, simply call the template without creating the child.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="produit-by-ITEMSET" match="produit" use="ITEMSET" />
  <xsl:template match="/produits">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="produit">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)[1])">
    <produit>
        <xsl:attribute name="ParentItem">
          <xsl:value-of select="ITEMSET"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count(key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)) > 1">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('produit-by-ITEMSET', ITEMSET)">
                <child>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="child" />
                </child>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="child" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </produit>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="produit" mode="child">
     <xsl:copy-of select="ITEMCODE" />
     <xsl:copy-of select="DESCR" />
     <xsl:copy-of select="EXTDESC" />
     <xsl:copy-of select="MANUF" />
     <xsl:copy-of select="IMAGE" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks it's 100% what I want !